# Start script.py after reboot as user xy in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, cron, debian-squeeze, init.d

How can i start a python script.py after a reboot as user xy in Debian Squeeze automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an entry in rc.local with something similar to the following:

```
su user_xy -c "script.py"
```

to execute the program *as* that user:

```
su - user_xy -c "script.py"
```

Comment: you can add sudo too ... `sudo su - user_xy -c "script.py" `

Comment: @Danielt. I would strongly advise *against* using `sudo` in rc startup scripts (mainly because those scripts are already running as root).

Comment: But how can i run it as user_xy, so the process is owned by user_xy?

Comment: su - user_xy -c "script.py"

note the dash.  updated answer, accept it if you don't have additional questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use @reboot entry in crontab of user root or user xy.
Debian cron supports such entries.

man -S5 crontab

```
string         meaning
------         -------
@reboot        Run once, at startup.
```